# unable to upload image to api endpoint with angular 6 reactive form

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using `Angular 6` and `Reactive Form`

I have to upload user avatar image and for that I have created a change-avatar component with following content.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {AccountService} from '../account.service';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-avatar-modal',
  templateUrl: './change-avatar-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-avatar-modal.component.css']
})
export class ChangeAvatarModalComponent implements OnInit {

  changeAvatarForm: FormGroup;

  @ViewChild('avatar') User_Avatar;
  userAvatarFile: File;

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.changeAvatarForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      avatar: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required
      ])
    });
  }

  get f() {
    return this.changeAvatarForm.controls;
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const image = this.User_Avatar.nativeElement;
    if (image.files && image.files[0]) {
      this.userAvatarFile = image.files[0];
    }
    const avatarFile: File = this.userAvatarFile;
    console.log(avatarFile);

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', avatarFile, avatarFile.name);

    console.log(formData);
    const data = {'avatar': formData};

    this.accountService.changeAvatar(data).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

and in template file

```
<form [formGroup]="changeAvatarForm" #formDir="ngForm" method="post" (submit)="onSubmit()">

    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="input-avatar" formControlName="avatar" #avatar>
    <button type="submit">Change Avatar</button>

</form>
```

But when I send `data` using `POST` to the API endpoint. It sends a blank `avatar` field.

Even the request payload has no data in it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file content, in other words, your `avatarFile` variable is just a handle to the selected file, you have to read the bytes out of the file handle you retrieved to get the actual file data using [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) like so

```
onSubmit() {
  const image = this.User_Avatar.nativeElement;
  if (image.files && image.files[0]) { 
    this.userAvatarFile = image.files[0]; 
  }
  const avatarFile: File = this.userAvatarFile;

  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  // Do your stuff only after you are done reading the file content
  // Reading starts after this block
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    console.log(avatarFile); 
    const formData: FormData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('fileName', avatarFile.name);
    // Edited here
    formData.append('fileData', new Blob([new Int16Array(fileReader.result)], {type: 'arraybuffer'});
    console.log(formData);
    const data = {'avatar': formData}; 
    this.accountService.changeAvatar(data)
                       .subscribe(res => { 
                         console.log(res); 
                       });
  };

  // Now actually start reading the file
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(avatarFile);
}
```

Comment: this is giving error `TS2345: Argument of type 'Int16Array' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.`

Comment: don't know why but `formData` created manually without any form in `HTML` actually consoles blank data.

Comment: Dont think you can view it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the formData only.

```
onSubmit() {
const image = this.User_Avatar.nativeElement;
if (image.files && image.files[0]) {
  this.userAvatarFile = image.files[0];
}
const avatarFile: File = this.userAvatarFile;
console.log(avatarFile);

const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('avatar', avatarFile, avatarFile.name);

console.log(formData);

this.accountService.changeAvatar(formData).subscribe(
  res => {
    console.log(res);
  }
);
```

}

Comment: I tried by passing `formData` only but still it was blank

Comment: @AnujTBE you can pass  const formData variable ?

Answer (score 0):

FileUpload In reactive Form you need to use $event to get the file content

Ref:https://medium.com/@amcdnl/file-uploads-with-angular-reactive-forms-960fd0b34cb5

@Component({
      template: 
        `<form [formGroup]="formGroup" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)" />
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid || formGroup.prestine">Submit</button>
        </form>`

    })
    export class PizzaComponent {

```
  formGroup = this.fb.group({
    file: [null, Validators.required]
  });

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  onFileChange(event) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    if(event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
      const [file] = event.target.files;
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      reader.onload = () => {
        this.formGroup.patchValue({
          file: reader.result
       });

        // need to run CD since file load runs outside of zone
        this.cd.markForCheck();
      };
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: this gives error as `DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string`

Comment: `reader.result` is giving base64 data. It seems error is from `patchValue()`